# What does "Lulala lila" mean in Cross Ange's music?

Tags: music, cross-ange

I recently watched the anime Cross Ange and I was curious about the phrase "Lulala lila" which is sung in the song Hikari no Uta. I'm pretty sure that phrase means something, but I still don't know what it is.

The phrase "Lulala lila" is not in Japanese and the word "Lila" means something divine in Hinduism. I just can't find the meaning of "Lulala" to understand the meaning of "Lulala lila" sung in the song.

This is a part of the lyrics of the song:

```
Hajimari no hikari kirali... kirali
Owari no hikari lulala lila

Kaesan El Ragna
Suna dokei wo
Toki wa afuren
Lulala lila
```

Comment: And as I said in the question, I'm sure that "Lulala lila" means something and this phrase is not there by chance.